# How can I add two values outside a view model KNOCKOUT JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

hi so I have a view model from where I am getting capital payment and capital paid, I am using a foreachloop like this which works.

```
//        self.capital_open = ko.computed(function() {
//            var sum = 0;
//            $.each(self.paymentdatas(), function (index, payment) {
//                 sum += parseFloat(payment.capital_payment()) - parseFloat(payment.capital_paid()) ; 
//            });
//            return sum.toFixed(2);
//        });
```

But since there is just one array from my view model I dont really have to use a foreach loop so my question is how can I just substract those two values without using a foreach loop.

I tried this way but isnt working.

```
self.capital_open = ko.computed(function() {
     var sum = 0;
     self.paymentdatas(), function (index, payment) {
     sum += parseFloat(payment.capital_payment()) - parseFloat(payment.capital_paid()) ; 
     }
  return sum.toFixed(2);
});
```

`paymentdatas()` contains one array with `capital_payment` and `capital_paid`

Comment: Could you show us what you get when you `console.log(self.paymentdatas())`? From the answers and your comments I feel there's some unclarity about your data format...

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = 0;
var result = paymentdatas();
return sum += parseFloat(result[0]) - parseFloat(result[1]);
```

did you try something like this ?

Comment: That wont work, since your using result 0 and 1  as 2 arrays where I stated there is only 1 array where I need to get the information from

Comment: I think i'm not undestanding all you problem well. But if result = the paymentdatas array, so result 0 and 1 are capital_payment and capital_paid. Or they are also array so, you'll need something more.

Comment: the for loop I used works, but instead of the for loop I just want to make subtraction for just one array since there is just 1 array in paymentdatas , if there was more arrays there I would use the for loop which would calculate me the sum of everything.

Comment: So its like paymendatas [ capital_payment, capital_paid ] ?

Answer (score 0):

ok, how about this:

```
self.capital_open = ko.computed(function() {
  var payment = parseFloat(self.paymentdatas().capital_payment());
  var paid = parseFloat(self.paymentdatas().capital_paid());
  return ( payment - paid ).toFixed(2);
});
```

Comment: so maybe it's not an array anymore? I mentioned it's an array, but maybe it's just an object...